# lsmod outputs: Not tainted

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I ran `lsmod` command on an emulator for a board, and the output is **`Not tainted`** . What does that mean ?

Comment: It's an indicator of "of kernel purity", read more here, http://askubuntu.com/questions/248470/what-does-the-kernel-taint-value-mean

Answer (score 8):

A running instance of the Linux kernel becomes “tainted” when something dodgy happens. The kernel boots in non-tainted state, and becomes tainted if one such dodgy thing happens. The full list of dodgy events is documented in [`sysctl/kernel.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt), and the kernel's current taint state can be read from `/proc/sys/kernel/tainted` (0 means not tainted).

The most common reason for tainting is loaded a module which declares a license other than GPL. All official kernel modules have a GPL license. Unofficial or experimental drivers that declare themselves as such also mark the kernel as tainted. Some internal kernel errors or hardware errors are recoverable, so the system keeps going, but mark the kernel as tainted.

The taint has no effect on the running kernel, but shows up in various traces and logs, including the output of `lsmod`. The social effect of taint is that kernel maintainers often won't help you if you're running a tainted kernel: you chose to do something dodgy and you have to live with the consequences.

Comment: But I think the problem here is that the kernel is not tainted respectively /proc/sys/kernel/tainted is 0 and lsmod prints "Not tainted". It's correct that it's not tainted but why does lsmod print "Not tainted"? Is this the default output if no modules are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Tainted is a kernel flag in the proc file system

```
$ /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
0
```

A value not null means normally that in case of an error or failure you should not blame kernel developers for this error or post some error reports to the kernel mailing list.

See also: [meaning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248470/what-does-the-kernel-taint-value-mean)