# What is a tainted Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, troubleshooting, proprietary-drivers

Under certain conditions, the Linux kernel may become *tainted*. For example, loading a proprietary video driver into the kernel taints the kernel. This condition may be visible in system logs, kernel error messages (oops and panics), and through tools such as `lsmod`, and remains until the system is rebooted.

What does this mean? Does it affect my ability to use the system, and how might it affect my support options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lsmod outputs: Not tainted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116847/lsmod-outputs-not-tainted)

Comment: @Gilles, I think the question you linked to should be merged into this one. Also, it's not obvious that one question is a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I'm hoping to make this the canonical version of the question; see the most recent edit to the question.

Comment: @DragonLord Why would you post a new question and try to close the existing one? Why not make that one the canonical version?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: 1) I didn't see the existing question, since it wasn't obvious that the user was asking "what does 'tainted' mean", and 2) the question as worded is rather specific to a single command, `lsmod`. I wrote this question and answer to make it more general so that someone asking "what does 'tainted' mean" can find it easily.

Comment: The kernel will also taint if code signing in effect but is missing even with open source drivers. Also see [e1000e driver built from sources is tainting kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50667433/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: They could have used a word that was a bit more neutral than "tainted".

Comment: @RogerDahl using a more neutral word would have missed the point they are trying to make. The statement is not neutral.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

A tainted kernel is one that is **in an unsupported state because it cannot be guaranteed to function correctly**. Most kernel developers will ignore bug reports involving tainted kernels, and community members may ask that you correct the tainting condition before they can proceed with diagnosing problems related to the kernel. In addition, some debugging functionality and API calls may be disabled when the kernel is tainted.

The taint state is indicated by a series of flags which represent the various reasons a kernel cannot be trusted to work properly. **The most common reason for the kernel to become tainted is loading a proprietary graphics driver from NVIDIA or AMD, in which case it is generally safe to ignore the condition.** However, some scenarios that cause the kernel to become tainted may be indicative of more serious problems such as failing hardware. It is a good idea to examine system logs and the specific taint flags set to determine the underlying cause of the issue.

This feature is intended to identify conditions which may make it difficult to properly troubleshoot a kernel problem. For example, a proprietary driver can cause problems that cannot be debugged reliably because its source code is not available and its effects cannot be determined. Likewise, if a serious kernel or hardware error had previously occurred, the integrity of the kernel space may have been compromised, meaning that any subsequent debug messages generated by the kernel may not be reliable.

Note that correcting the tainting condition alone does not remove the taint state because doing so does not change the fact that the kernel can no longer be relied on to work correctly or produce accurate debugging information. **The system must be restarted to clear the taint flags.**

**More information is available in the Linux kernel documentation**, including [what each taint flag means](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html) and [how to troubleshoot a tainted kernel prior to reporting bugs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/reporting-issues.html#check-taint-flag).

A partial list of conditions that can result in the kernel being tainted follows, each with their own flags. Note that some Linux vendors, such as SUSE, [add additional taint flags](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016321) to indicate conditions such as loading a module that is supported by a third party rather than directly by the vendor.

- Loading a proprietary (or non-GPL-compatible) kernel module. As noted above, this is the most common reason for the kernel to become tainted.
- The use of *staging* drivers, which are part of the kernel source code but are experimental and not fully tested.
- The use of *out-of-tree* modules that are not included with the Linux kernel source code.
- Forcibly loading or unloading modules. This can happen if one is trying to use a module that is not built for the current version of the kernel. (The Linux kernel module [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is not stable across versions, or even differently-configured builds of the same version.)
- Running a kernel on certain hardware configurations that are specifically not supported, such as an SMP (multiprocessor) kernel on early AMD Athlon processors not supporting SMP operation.
- Overriding the [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) DSDT in the kernel. This is sometimes needed to correct for firmware power-management bugs; see [this Arch Linux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT) for details.
- Certain critical error conditions, such as [machine check exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) and [kernel oopses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_oops).
- Certain serious bugs in the BIOS, UEFI, or other system firmware which the kernel must work around.

Comment: This answer is missing a lot of information from the dup this question displaced.

Comment: I would add at least one important possibility of the "unsigned module" scenario -- a kernel rootkit was loaded into the kernel or kernel exploit was just executed.

Comment: I've overhauled the answer in a series of edits to make it more accurate and easier to read, and have removed the unnecessary list of taint flags (readers can simply click through the kernel documentation link).

Answer (score 3):

Loading a proprietary or non-GPL-compatible module or unsigned module will set a 'taint' flag in the running kernel.

To check the kernel tainted state in kernel logs:

```
journalctl -k | grep taint
```

To check the kernel tainted state at runtime:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted      // if 0 then kernel is not tainted, else it is.
```

The returned value is a bit field; you can find the bit meanings in [this table](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html#table-for-decoding-tainted-state).

In a kernel panic message, look for a line starting with ‘CPU:’

‘Not tainted:’ if the kernel was not tainted at the time of the kp event; if it was, then it will print ‘Tainted:’.

Reference: [The Linux Kernel documentation on tainted kernels](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html).