# How to understand the modinfo output?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm just trying to understand the `modinfo` output that describes a kernel module. For instance, in the case of the module `i915`, the output looks like this:

```
$ modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
[...]
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
alias:          pci:v00008086d00005A84sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
[...]
depends:        drm_kms_helper,drm,video,button,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=DRM_I915_KMS from .config, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
[...]
```

I'm able to understand some of the fields, but I have no idea what the following mean:

- `firmware`
- `alias`
- `intree`
- `vermagic`

Does anyone know how to interpret them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**firmware**:

```
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
```

Many devices need two things to run properly. A driver and a firmware. The driver requests the firmware from the filesystem at `/lib/firmware`. This is a special file, needed by the hardware, it's not a binary. The diver then does what it needs to do to load the firmware into the device. The firmware does programming the hardware inside the device.

---

**alias**:

```
alias:          pci:v00008086d00005A84sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
```

This can be splitted up in the part after the characters:

- `v00008086`: `v` stands for the *vendor id*, it identifies a hardware manufacturer. That list is maintained by the [PCI Special Interest Group](http://pcisig.com/). Your number [0x8086](http://pcidatabase.com/search.php?vendor_search_str=0x8086&vendor_search=Search) stands for "Intel Corporation".
- `d00005A84`: `d` stands for the *device id*, which is selected by the manufacturer. This ID is usually paired with the vendor ID to make a unique 32-bit identifier for a hardware device. There is no offical list and I wasn't able to find a Intel device id list to lookup that number.
- `sv*`, `sd*`: The *subsystem vendor version* and *subsystem device version* are for further identification of a device (`*` indicates that it will match anything)
- `bc03`: The *base class*. It defines what kind of device it is; `IDE interface`, `Ethernet controller`, `USB Controller`, ... `bc03` stands for `Display controller`. You may notice them from the output of `lspci`, because `lspci` maps the number to the device class.
- `sc*`: A *sub class* to the base class.
- `i*`: interface

---

**intree**:

```
intree:         Y
```

All kernel modules start their developments as `out-of-tree`. Once a module gets accepted to be included, it becomes an `in-tree` module. A modules without that flag (set to `N`) could [taint the kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel).

---

**vermagic**:

```
vermagic:       4.2.0-1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

When loading a module, the strings in the `vermagic` value are checked if they match. If they don't match you will get an error and the kernel refuses to load the module. You can overcome that by using the `--force` flag of `modprobe`. Naturally, these checks are there for your protection, so using  this option is dangerous.