# Are there any real downsides to running a tainted kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm modifying a couple of drivers in order to implement a small piece of low-level convenience functionality, and in doing so tainting my kernel due to out-of-tree modules. I'm well aware that in most cases it shouldn't be a problem, although before reporting a bug or other issue I should reproduce it with an untainted kernel. However, I have also seen a few places, such as in the accepted answer of [What is a tainted Linux kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/what-is-a-tainted-linux-kernel) (first paragraph), that having a tainted kernel may have worsened/fewer debugging features. I have not been able to find any official documentation to back that claim up nor do any of the places I've seen it have any additional information.

Is this a just an internet rumor, or is there something I need to be aware of for when I find myself trying to track down an issue in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tainted kernel only has very slight differences in behaviour, and only to protect itself, never to disable features just because it’s tainted:

- [the check for hung uninterruptible tasks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/hung_task.c#L178) aborts early if the kernel is tainted with `TAINT_DIE` (*i.e.* an Oops or `BUG()` has occurred);
- [trace events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.4/source/kernel/trace/trace_events.c#L2922) and [enums](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.4/source/kernel/trace/trace.c#L9649) aren’t set up for tainted kernel modules where the taint could result in incorrect trace data; if a module is tainted for reasons *other* than being out-of-tree, staging, or unsigned, its state could be invalid and tracing it might cause more problems (think for example of modules which are force-inserted in spite of an ABI mismatch).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful